# Does arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ have reliable C++0x support

Tags: c++, c++11, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I tried to use arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ compiler (from g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf package) to compile simple program with lambda expressions, with -std=c++0x switch. It works. Does anybody have experience using C++0x features with this compiler? I want to know, whether this support is reliable and safe for use.

The package is from Ubuntu repository, OS is updated (12.04 32 bits). Version: arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Comment: Which compiler version? Package from where?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `--version` flag to get the GCC version. Then, consult the [C++-11 feature matrix](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) to see which features you can use on that particular version.

Comment: 4.6.3 - according to this table, most features are supported. I will keep this question opened some time - maybe somebody really works with C++0x on this compiler, and can share his experience. Then I will accept this answer.

Comment: This is **the** answer, check your compiler version and consult the feature matrix. And maybe even the release notes and bug database.